# Encrypted sparsebundle password appears to be cached

Tags: terminal, sparsebundle

I use this command to mount an encrypted volume:

```
hdiutil mount ~/Documents/secret.sparsebundle/
```

On first use I'm prompted for a password. I then close it either by clicking 'eject' in finder or the matching `hdiutil unmount` command.

If I try and re-open it using the original command, I'm sometimes granted access without the password challenge. This appears to occur across terminal sessions and (overnight) screen locks.

Is this expected behaviour or a bug? How do I ensure that the passwords are not cached?

Comment: I've had a look in my keychain and there's no mention of it there. The Mac is only a week old and is pretty close to a fresh install so it was easy going through all the entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `hdiutil` man page:

```
unmount volume [-force]
            unmount a mounted volume without detaching any associated
            image.  Volume is a /dev entry or mountpoint.  NOTE: unmount
            does NOT detach any disk image associated with the volume.
            Images are attached and detached; volumes are mounted and
            unmounted.  hdiutil mountvol (or diskutil mount) will remount
            a volume that has been unmounted by hdiutil unmount.
```

The image encryption key isn't discarded until the image is detached, so after `hdiutil unmount` you'll be able to remount it without supplying the password. Solution: use `hdiutil detach` (or the eject button in Finder) instead.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of detach. There was a fundamental gap in my understanding!