# Mounting password-protected sparsebundle doesn't ask for password

Tags: password, mount, sparsebundle

I have an encrypted, password-protected sparsebundle that I occasionally mount and unmount from the terminal. I want the system to ask for the password every time I mount it, but for some reason it keeps remembering.

This is how I mount it: `hdiutil attach ~/path/to/my/bundle -mountpoint ~/my/mountpoint`

These are some of the ways I've tried to unmount it:

```
hdiutil detach -force ~/path/to/my/bundle
hdiutil detach -force /Users/me/path/to/my/bundle
hdiutil eject -force ~/path/to/my/bundle
diskutil eject ~/path/to/my/bundle
diskutil unmount force ~/path/to/my/bundle
```

(I've read [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230572/encrypted-sparsebundle-password-appears-to-be-cached) that `hdiutil unmount` is not sufficient to make the system forget the password.)

However, whatever I try, the system "helpfully" remembers the password each time.

Only when I use the eject button in Finder, does the system forget the password.

**EDIT:** Also, there is no entry in my keychain that suggest the password has been cached. (At least, I can't find it. There are none with kind `disk image password`.)

What am I missing here? How can I make sure the sytem **always** asks for the password, each time I mount the sparsebundle?

**EDIT 2:** I've created a new sparsebundle, with a new name and a different password, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels kind of sad, but in the end I managed to find a way to do it using AppleScript:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to eject "<name>"'
```

The `<name>` should match the name in Finder's sidebar.

Answer (score 2):

Your password is probably stored in your Keychain. Remove that entry and you will be forced to enter the password every time.

Comment: I've looked there but I couldn't find it. What name could it have?

Comment: Sort by `Kind` and look for `disk image password`. I just did and only had one such entry. It was called `imagename.sparsebundle`

Comment: Alas, no `disk image password` in there...